# Java: "cons" an item to a list

Tags: java, list, guava

I have an `Item` which has a method `List<Item> getChildren()` (which returns an immutable list) and for each of the items I have, I need to create a list of the item followed by its children.

What's the quickest way to "[cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)" (in the Lisp/Scheme sense) my item to create a new immutable list? I can certainly do the following, but it seems wrong/wasteful:

```
public List<Item> getItemAndItsChildren(Item item)
{
    if (item.getChildren.isEmpty())
        return Collections.singletonList(item);
    else
    {
        // would rather just "return cons(item, item.getChildren())"
        // than do the following -- which, although straightforward,
        // seems wrong/wasteful.
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(item);
        items.addAll(item.getChildren());
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems pretty good to me.

Regards, Stéphane

Comment: There are no `cons` methods in the Java Collections framework (that I know of, and I just checked as well), however you could write a method called cons that performs this, so you don't have to write the ugly implementation everywhere. You could also 'skip' a line of code: `items.add(item);`, as you can call the `ArrayList` constructor that takes a `Collection`.

Comment: If you are trying to do a `cons` is it really a requirement to adhere to the `List` interface, or could that requirement be relaxed?  `List` has some baggage with allowing random-access, reverse iteration, etc.

Comment: re: guava -- I figured guava might have something -- and I'm using it already whereas I don't tend to use Apache Commons anymore.

Answer (score 7):

I'd change my requirements. In most cases, you don't need a `List` in your interface, an `Iterable` will do nicely. Here's the method:

```
public Iterable<Item> getItemWithChildren(Item item)    {
    return Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(
        Iterables.concat(
            Collections.singleton(item),
            item.getChildren()
        )
    );
}
```

and here's the shortened version (with static imports):

```
return unmodifiableIterable(concat(singleton(item), item.getChildren()));
```

Comment: (I'm calling a method in an interface not under my control that requires a `List<>`, not an iterable)

Comment: @Jason in that case I'd wrap it with [`ImmutableList.copyOf(iterable)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf%28java.lang.Iterable%29) (removing the `unmodifiableIterable()`, of course)

Answer (score 3):

The ability to create a new immutable list by concatenating a head element to a tail that may be shared between other lists requires a singly-linked list implementation. Java doesn't provide anything like this out of the box, so your `ArrayList` solution is as good as anything.

It's also going to be relatively efficient, assuming that these lists are short-lived and you don't have tens of thousands of element in the list. If you do, and *if this operation is taking a significant portion of your execution time*, then implmenting your own single-linked list might be worthwhile.

My one change to improve your existing efficiency: construct the new list with a capacity (1 + size of old list).

Comment: good explanation of what is the point of using cons, yet I think the code might be a bit better using guava ImmutableList.Builder.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to special case an Item with no children.

```
public List<Item> getItemAndItsChildren(Item item)
{
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(item);
    items.addAll(item.getChildren());
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(items);
}
```

Also, if you are looking to use a language that isn't verbose, then Java is a poor choice.  I'm sure you can do what you like in far less code in Groovy and Scala which both run on the JVM.  (Not to mention JRuby or Jython.)

Comment: I don't mind the amount of code, I do mind the fact that a new array list is created when it really doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for something like a `CompositeList`, similar to the [Apache Commons' `CompositeCollection`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/collection/CompositeCollection.html).  An implementation could be as naive as this:

```
public class CompositeList<T> extends AbstractList<T>{
    private final List<T> first, second;

    public CompositeList(List<T> first, List<T> second) {
        this.second = second;
        this.first = first;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        if ( index < first.size() ) {
            return first.get(index);
        } else {
            return second.get(index - first.size());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return first.size() + second.size();
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
public List<Item> getItemAndItsChildren(Item item)
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableList( 
        new CompositeList<Item>(Collections.singletonList(item), item.getChildren()) );
}
```

But there are huge caveats that make such a class difficult to use...the main problem being that the `List` interface cannot itself mandate that it is unmodifiable.  If you are going to use something like this you **must** ensure that clients of this code never modify the children!

Comment: so if the child items are known to be immutable, this is OK?

Comment: @Jason: it's not the immutability of the items that matters but rather the immutability of the child lists you pass in.

Comment: right, I didn't state that correctly -- I was thinking of the collection of the child items, not the items themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I use these. (using guava's ImmutableList and Iterables)

```
/** Returns a new ImmutableList with the given element added */
public static <T> ImmutableList<T> add(final Iterable<? extends T> list, final T elem) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.concat(list, Collections.singleton(elem)));
}

/** Returns a new ImmutableList with the given elements added */
public static <T> ImmutableList<T> add(final Iterable<? extends T> list, final Iterable<? extends T> elems) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.concat(list, elems));
}

/** Returns a new ImmutableList with the given element inserted at the given index */
public static <T> ImmutableList<T> add(final List<? extends T> list, final int index, final T elem) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.concat(list.subList(0, index), Collections.singleton(elem), list.subList(index, list.size())));
}

/** Returns a new ImmutableList with the given element inserted at the given index */
public static <T> ImmutableList<T> add(final List<? extends T> list, final int index, final Iterable<?extends T> elems) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.concat(list.subList(0, index), elems, list.subList(index, list.size())));
}
```

But none of them are efficient.

Example of prepending/consing an item to a list:

```
ImmutableList<String> letters = ImmutableList.of("a", "b", "c");
add(letters, 0, "d");
```

For more efficient immutable/persistent collections you should, as @eneveu points out, look at pcollections, although I have no idea what the quality of that library is.

Comment: It seems that Iterables.concat uses Iterators.concat, which returns an iterator which cannot remove elements if the iterators passed cannot remove either, and that seems to be the case with the original post. If so, you ought to be able to skip the slow ImmutableList.copyOf() operation, if you can live with an Iterable instead of a List interface.

Answer (score 1):

[pcollections](http://code.google.com/p/pcollections/) is a persistent Java collection library you might be interested in. I bookmarked it a while ago, and haven't yet used it, but the project seems relatively active.

If you want to use Guava, you could use the unmodifiable view returned by [Lists.asList(E first, E[] rest)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#asList%28E,%20E%5B%5D%29). It works with arrays, and its primary goal is to simplify the use of var-args methods. But I see no reason you couldn't use it in your case:

```
public List<Item> getItemAndItsChildren(Item item) {
    return Lists.asList(item, item.getChildren().toArray());
}
```

The `List` returned is an unmodifiable view, but it may change if the source array is modified. In your case, it's not a problem, since the getChildren() method returns an immutable list. Even if it were mutable, the `toArray()` method [supposedly returns a "safe" array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)...

If you want to be extra safe, you could do:

```
public ImmutableList<Item> getItemAndItsChildren(Item item) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(Lists.asList(item, item.getChildren().toArray()));
}
```

Note that `Lists.asList()` avoids un-necessary `ArrayList` instantiation, since it's a view. Also, `ImmutableList.copyOf()` would delegate to `ImmutableList.of(E element)` when the children list is empty (which, similarly to `Collections.singletonList()`, is space-efficient).

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate your list with the exact number you will be putting into it to eliminate expansion copies when you add more.

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

should be

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(item.getChildren() + 1);
```

otherwise what you are doing is about as idiomatic Java as you can get.

Another thing, is you might consider using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and its [ImmutableList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) implementation rather than an `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

> Unlike `Collections.unmodifiableList(java.util.List)`, which is a view
>   of a separate collection that can still change, an instance of
>   `ImmutableList` contains its own private data and will never change.
>   `ImmutableList` is convenient for public static final lists ("constant
>   lists") and also lets you easily make a "defensive copy" of a list
>   provided to your class by a caller.